# Create array from SQL queries running very slow

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have been working on this for a while and have finally made things work how I want them to work.  I realise that my code is super inefficient and this is showing by the really long time it takes to load the data.

I am using SQL queries to create an array as follows...

```
function table_data()
{
global $wpdb;
$blogusers = get_users('blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=client');
$form = GFFormsModel::get_form_meta( '337' ); 
        foreach( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
        if ( $field['adminLabel'] == 'I_BD' )
            $clientid_field = $field['id'];
        }
$example_data = array();
    foreach ($blogusers as $user)
        {

        $todaysdate = date("Y-m-d");
        $count0 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM l_detail a JOIN g_lead b ON b.id = a.l_id WHERE a.value = '$user->user_login' AND b.date_created LIKE '%$todaysdate%' AND a.field_number = '$clientid_field'" );

        $onedayago = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( '-1 days' ) );
        $count1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM l_detail a JOIN g_lead b ON b.id = a.l_id WHERE a.value = '$user->user_login' AND b.date_created LIKE '%$onedayago%' AND a.field_number = '$clientid_field'" );

        $twodaysago = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( '-2 days' ) );
        $count2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM l_detail a JOIN g_lead b ON b.id = a.l_id WHERE a.value = '$user->user_login' AND b.date_created LIKE '%$twodaysago%' AND a.field_number = '$clientid_field'" );

        $threedaysago = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( '-3 days' ) );
        $count3 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM l_detail a JOIN g_lead b ON b.id = a.l_id WHERE a.value = '$user->user_login' AND b.date_created LIKE '%$threedaysago%' AND a.field_number = '$clientid_field'" );

        $fourdaysago = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( '-4 days' ) );
        $count4 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM l_detail a JOIN g_lead b ON b.id = a.l_id WHERE a.value = '$user->user_login' AND b.date_created LIKE '%$fourdaysago%' AND a.field_number = '$clientid_field'" );

        $fivedaysago = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( '-5 days' ) );
        $count5 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM l_detail a JOIN g_lead b ON b.id = a.l_id WHERE a.value = '$user->user_login' AND b.date_created LIKE '%$fivedaysago%' AND a.field_number = '$clientid_field'" );

        $sixdaysago = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( '-6 days' ) );
        $count6 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM l_detail a JOIN g_lead b ON b.id = a.l_id WHERE a.value = '$user->user_login' AND b.date_created LIKE '%$sixdaysago%' AND a.field_number = '$clientid_field'" );

        $arrData=array("client"=>"$user->user_login","sixdaysago"=>$count6[0]->count,"fivedaysago"=>$count5[0]->count,"fourdaysago"=>$count4[0]->count,"threedaysago"=>$count3[0]->count,"twodaysago"=>$count2[0]->count,"yesterday"=>$count1[0]->count,"today"=>$count0[0]->count,"total"=>$count[0]->count);
        array_push($example_data, $arrData);
    }   
    return $example_data;
}
```

As I mentioned, this works correctly but takes so long to process the data that sometimes the server crashes.

How can I make this more efficient?  I realise I have probably written this in completely the wrong way so am looking to be schooled!

Comment: Just reading your query makes me think of Valley Girls,  "created like six days ago" but I digress.  Why are you using like?  Shouldn't the date be equivalent to something?

Comment: consider using a single query that groups by your time types...then loop over the result set and get the data you need... doing this many count function calls is very expensive

Comment: You might also want to use a view or materialized view

Comment: What is the type of `date_created` field?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all this data with a single query. Just select all rows less than 7 days old, then group by user id and DAY(date_created). You can then read that data into any appropriate multidimensional array as needed for output. Make sure all columns used in joins, filtering and grouping have indexes.